# Importing ES6 modules in CommonJS Node app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules, commonjs

Long story short, I am trying to use an npm package that only has an ES6 module entrypoint, namely the `bids-validator` ([GitHub](https://github.com/bids-standard/bids-validator)), in a CommonJS module as my entire 50+ module app is built in CommonJS. According to the Node [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_require), the standard way to do this is using the `import()` function. I tried this approach, with the following code:

```
async function importValidator() {
  const { validate } = await import('bids-validator')
  return validate
}

const validate = importValidator()
```

However, this results in an error from the `bids-validator` package, not necessarily the import function above:

```
error: unhandledRejection: Cannot use import statement outside a module
/*/app/api/node_modules/bids-validator/index.js:2
import validate from './validators'
```

Is there a way to circumvent this, so that I could use the package within a CommonJS module?

Comment: Side note: `const validate = importValidator()` just assigns a promise to `validate`.

Comment: What version of Node.js are you using?

Comment: Good point regarding the promise. I will use `validate` in an async function, so I can do the import there anyway.

Comment: I'm using Node 14.16.0.

Comment: FYI, it doesn't work if you try to import it from an ESM module, either. I think the package is (presumably temporarily) broken. For one thing, I notice it doesn't have `"type": "module"` in its `package.json`. If I add it, the first line of its `index.js` (`import validate from './validators'`) triggers the error *"Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import '/home/tjc/temp/bidtest/node_modules/bids-validator/validators' is not supported"*

Comment: Thanks for testing that, I actually tried it myself earlier too and had the same problem although I wasn't sure if it was just me. The CLI provided by the package works just fine though, and same goes for in-browser use via webpack. Makes me wonder if they tested it within a Node app at all.

Comment: I think you should increase your node version to 21.2.0